Google Sheets IF(TIMEVALUE) function using a range (ARRAYFUNCTION) errors
I am using a form to have time information input into a sheet (this is only one aspect of the sheet that is used in other calculations). I have old time data that was from an archive file that has time in a value of duration, ie 28:00:00, or 28 hours. The new data being input is using a start time, an end time, and a number of employees to calculate the duration, ie 8:00:00 AM - 12:00:00 PM * 10 = 40:00:00 (40 hours) duration. My issue is that I have this formula
=IF(ISBLANK(I2000) + ISBLANK(J2000), N2000 + O2000, SUMPRODUCT((TIMEVALUE(J2000) - TIMEVALUE(I2000)) - IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(I2000) < TIMEVALUE("12:00 PM"), TIMEVALUE(J2000) > TIMEVALUE("12:30 PM")), 1/48, 0), H2000)))

This formula works well and properly calculates the duration in columns N + O if there is a time duration input, or it calculates the duration of time worked (including a 30 minute break if applicable). This works individually on numbered rows. If I adjust this to a range I receive an error of "#VALUE error TIMEVALUE parameter " cannot be parsed to date/time." That led me to using ARRAYFORMULA, but I am still receiving the same error. This is the current formula I am using. Is there a way to get this to function properly? I need to have this function in an array because the sheet that it is filtering data from is regularly sorted by a production date and when the sort changes, it doesn't adjust the formula for that row.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(I2:I) + ISBLANK(J2:J), N2:N + O2:O, SUMPRODUCT((TIMEVALUE(J2:J) - TIMEVALUE(I2:I)) - IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(I2:I) < TIMEVALUE("12:00 PM"), TIMEVALUE(J2:J) > TIMEVALUE("12:30 PM")), 1/48, 0), H2:H)))


Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your data in text markdown format.

This is your formula adjusted to return multiple rows. It will return an empty value for any row where none of  i,j,n,o contain a value. You can constrain the ranges by setting an ending row.
=LET(h,H2:H, i,I2:I, j,J2:J, n,N2:N, o,O2:O,
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(LEN(TEXTJOIN(,1, i, j, n, o)),
      IF(ISBLANK(i)+ISBLANK(j), n+o,
        h*((j*1-i*1)-(i*1<0.5)*(j*1>25/48)*(1/48))),)))

Or the equivalent
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(LEN(TEXTJOIN(,1, I2:I, J2:J, N2:N, O2:O)),
      IF(ISBLANK(I2:I)+ISBLANK(J2:J), N2:N+O2:O,
        H2:H*((J2:J*1-I2:I*1)-(I2:I*1<0.5)*(J2:J*1>25/48)*(1/48))),)))

Or
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(LEN(TEXTJOIN(,1, H2:H)),
      IF(ISBLANK(I2:I)+ISBLANK(J2:J), N2:N+O2:O,
        H2:H*((TIMEVALUE(J2:J)-TIMEVALUE(I2:I))-(TIMEVALUE(I2:I)<0.5)*
          (TIMEVALUE(J2:J)>25/48)*(1/48))),)))




Performance
Purely out of interest I ran some performance comparisons between the formulas based on x*1 vs. TIMEVALUE(x) as well as with and without LET.  The results in the table below are representative although the actual numbers varied by iteration.
Some takeaways:

Working with numerical durations using x*1 ran about 3.5x times the speed of TIMEVALUE(x)
Working with text string durations using x*1 ran about 1.5x times the speed of TIMEVALUE(x)
Writing the formula with or without LET didn't have an appreciable effect on any formula's performance, which reflects that LET was only used for typing reduction and prettifying the code rather than storing calculation results for reuse.
Increasing the number of populated and unpopulated rows being tested by a factor of x had a comparable effect on execution time which would also increase by the same factor.

Results Table

Dataset was 3,000 populated of a 5,000 row sheet

"(multiple)" represents the execution time relative to the slowest formula in that column.

Times are formatted as minutes:seconds.milliseconds so even the slowest formula, at 49 milliseconds, is plenty fast for your needs however for more complex formulas knowing which building blocks will run 3x faster can have a significant and sometimes exponential impact.



Formula Type
Used LET
ISNUMBER(x)
ISTEXT(x)






Elapsed   (multiple)
Elapsed   (multiple)


x*1
yes
0:00.013   (3.8x)
0:00.026   (1.6x)


x*1
-
0:00.014   (3.5x)
0:00.027   (1.6x)


TIMEVALUE(x)
yes
0:00.045   (1.1x)
0:00.042   (1.0x)


TIMEVALUE(x)
-
0:00.049   (1.0x)
0:00.040   (1.1x)






These all work for the rows that have no data in I or J (start time and end time), but output the error "#NAME? - unknown range name: H. " in the rows with data in I.
Additionally for simplicity of the formula, J will never have data without I having data, and I will never have data if N has data. The only criteria that needs to be searched is "is there data in  'I'? If so use this first formula (N:N+O:O), otherwise use the second.

I was able to correct the issue by defining the H range in the first LET instance. Thanks for the help.
